# Prove that these are not pairwise isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Prove $\mathbb Z_s$, $G_s$ (the group of symmetries of the square) and the quaternion group $Q$ are not pairwise isomorphic.

How would you go about proving. Seems quite difficult. I know that none of the latter two can be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_8$ because it is abelian and they are not....

Comment: The identical question was asked and closed a few days ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255913 See the comments there: count the numbers of elements of order $2$ in $D_8$ and $Q_8$.

Comment: How would you write the proof

Comment: I would say that $D_8$ (which you called $G_s$) contains exactly $a$ elements of order $2$ and $Q_8$ contains exactly $b$ elements of order $2$, where $a \ne b$, and therefore the two groups are not isomorphic. But I am leaving it to you to calculate $a$ and $b$.